# Python: traverse all directories under /mydir and remove all files with "(1)" in name

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all files with `(1)` in the name under `/mydir` and subdirectories. I have searched and found a script on how to find all files with `*.txt` as below. How to replace the `if` condition sentence to find all files with `(1)` in the name?

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mydir"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: try `file.contains("(1)")`

Comment: In Python this is really easy: `if "(1)" in file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```py
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mydir"):
    for file in files:
        if "(1)" in file:
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```

First we import the `os` module for `walk`, `remove`, and `join` methods. Then iterate over the tuples yielded by `os.walk`. Then iterate over the files returned and check whether the filename contains the string "(1)". If it matches, we concatenate the file name with the directory using `os.path.join` and then remove the file with `os.remove`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easy with `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path
for file in Path("/mydir").glob("*(1)*.*"):
    print(file)
    #file.unlink()
```

My recommendation is to print all files to delete first (as shown), and only uncomment the `file.unlink()` line once you are sure that the right files will be deleted.